# Explicitly showing cokernel of exponential sequence is not a sheaf

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, sheaf-theory

In the classical example of short exact sequence of presheaves $$0\rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathcal O_X \rightarrow \mathcal F \rightarrow 1,$$ it is well known that $\mathcal F$ is not a sheaf because there are functions that admit a logarithm locally but not globally. I'm trying to make sense this statement more vividly by giving explicit open sets $U_i$ such that I can find $f_i \in \mathcal F(U_i)$ which agree on the intersections but cannot be lifted to a global $f\in\mathcal F(\cup U_i)$. After all, that's the way of showing that $\mathcal F$ is not a sheaf, right?

My idea was to show that I cannot patch up $log(x)$ over some non-simply connected open set that goes around the origin. Of course, $log(x)$ cannot exist in such a set, but my problem is in finding a cover of such a set such that a $log(x)$ does exist in each component and *agree* on the intersections. Making them agree is the hard part, and the best I could do was the following:

Pick $U_1$ to be the pointed disk around the origin with a cut along the negative real axis and $U_2$ some open, simply connected set meeting the cut but not the origin. In this way $U_2$ would "bridge over the cut", and the union of the two sets would not be able to contain some $f$ which restricts to $log(x)$ in $U_1, U_2$. The problem is that my $U_1$ and $U_2$ do not satisfy the glueability condition of having some $f_i$ which agree on the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is a simply connected open of $\Bbb C$, you have an exact sequence $0(U) \to \Bbb Z(U) \xrightarrow{2i\pi} \Gamma(U,\Bbb C) \xrightarrow{\exp} \Gamma(U,\Bbb C^*) \to 0(U)$.

The sheaf who is locally the holomorphic functions to $\Bbb C^*$, is the sheaf of holomorphic functions to $\Bbb C^*$.

But if you pick $U = \Bbb C^*$, the sequence of abelian groups $0(\Bbb C^*) \to \Bbb Z(\Bbb C^*) \xrightarrow{2i\pi} \Gamma(\Bbb C^*,\Bbb C) \xrightarrow{\exp} \Gamma(\Bbb C^*,\Bbb C^*) \to 0(\Bbb C^*)$ is not exact. For example, the identity map $id_{\Bbb C^*} \in \Gamma(\Bbb C^*,\Bbb C^*)$ is not in the image of $\Gamma(\Bbb C^*,\Bbb C)$ by $\exp$ (because there is no logarithm function defined on all $\Bbb C^*$).

If you define $\mathcal F(U) = coker (\Bbb Z(U) \xrightarrow{2i\pi} \Gamma(U,\Bbb C))$, then this is not a sheaf : let $U_\pm = \Bbb C \setminus \Bbb R^\pm$, you have elements $\log_\pm \in \mathcal F(U_\pm)$ given by the classes of the logarithm functions $\log_\pm : U_\pm \to \Bbb C$ modulo $\Bbb Z(U_\pm)$. They agree on $U_+ \cap U_-$. Not because the functions themselves agree, but because $(\log_+ - \log_-)/2i\pi$ is an element of $\Bbb Z(U_+ \cap U_-)$ : it is an integer-valued locally constant function.
But their glueing doesn't correspond to the class of any function $\log : \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C$. So there is no element in $\mathcal F(\Bbb C^*)$ whose restrictions are the $\log_\pm$.

Comment: Thank you! I had not realized that we only needed the functions to agree as elements of the classes modulo locally constant multiples of $2\pi i$. But now that you put it this way, can you also clarify what you mean by "their glueing doesn't correspond to the class of any log"? How do you glue classes of functions? Do you pick a random representative in $\mathcal F(U_-)$ and extend it over $\mathbb R^-$ by setting the values there to be equal to the values of any random representative in $\mathcal F(U_+)$? And then you say that no choice of representative in $\mathcal F(U_+)$ would have glued

Comment: into a holomorphic function?